# In what ways are main characters suboptimal in Order of the Stick?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, character-advancement

A motif of the Web comic [*Order of the Stick*](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/ootscast.html)—which largely uses *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* rules—is its subversion of that game's stereotypes. Some commentators suggest that, from an optimzation standpoint, the main cast (except, perhaps, Elan) is mechanically pretty terrible. (For example, some say that there's a mismatch between cast members' ability scores and their chosen classes.)

Although the author's never published statistics for the characters, what evidence from the stips (and elsewhere) exists that the strip's main cast has made less-than-stellar character-building choices?

Comment: Could those who think this is too opinion-based please indicate how this question could be improved to be less so? Or otherwise, why are the other 420 optimization-related questions on this site not opinion-based?

Comment: @vsz Those other optimization questions aren't "why are the characters in a comedy webcomic poorly optimized", so this isn't really in the same category as them. (Why *should* they be optimized though? Aren't they suboptimal because of it making for good comedy?)

Comment: @doppelgreener : Ok, now I see your point. But I hope you also see mine. A fighter with a very high Intelligence score, and a ranger with a very low Wisdom (thanks, Phillip) and no class-specific skills are blatantly sub-optimal (bordering on useless in a traditional 3.5 combat-heavy campaign). I was only searching for similar blatantly "unorthodox" aspects in the builds of the other characters.

Comment: This is a request to opinion-analyze (with no specific goal) undocumented builds of a whole party of cartoon characters. That doesn't fit the parameters of good charop questions as defined here. http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-optimization-questions-on-topic

Comment: The answer to the question *Why are they suboptimal?* is less a gaming question and more of writing question, but a question like *In what way is each main character mechanically suboptimal?* I think can be answered by an *OotS* expert using evidence from the strips and around the Web and might make a good read. (*Note:* I am not such an expert.) Such a question might be of interest to a *3.5* player who thought such characters *were* optimized!

Comment: @HeyICanChan at that point a question like "what are the main OOTS characters' builds?" might also be worthwhile, since whoever's looking into that is going to have to research a large portion of their builds (and what if some of them *aren't* suboptimal?)

Comment: @doppelgreener I'm not sure *What are their builds?* is exactly answerable, though. That is, it isn't speculation to say that, for example, Roy actually *is* a high-Int fighter, but determining his *exact* level and feats might be impossible. However, explaining that *being* a high Int fighter in *3.5e* is a suboptimal choice is part of an answer with legs.

Comment: @Miniman An answer saying that an answer is impossible is *still* an answer. That is, one *OotS* expert might think it's impossible to determine the optimization level of the characters *at all*, but another expert might have a different opinion. And an answer that explains why each character can be *perceived* as suboptimal when, in fact, each character *isn't* might be exactly the kind of answer the asker's looking for.

Comment: @Miniman My first comment includes *using evidence from the strips and around the Web*, and a good answer should. Many questions have answers based on educated and expert opinions. Is there something about this question or topic *in particular* that's uncomfortable?

Comment: @Miniman Make a room. I'll be there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46504/discussion-between-miniman-and-hey-i-can-chan).

Comment: At this point, I'm not sure what the question is meant to accomplish. “Please explain all suboptimal build choice jokes in OotS” is more of a media-consumption question now than a practically-meaningful/useful RPG question. (That observation is not meant to be a “list questions are bad” point; I'm seeing a topicality doubt that's a problem for the Q long before listyness can be considered a problem.)

Comment: The question asker directed to the GiTP forums where entire threads have been devoted to class and build geekery based on detailed strip analysis.  Needless to say, there isn't a "best" answer and for that matter  not much consensus.  If the author of OoTS won't choose to list the actual builds (and I don't blame him for not doing so, given his stated points in numerous comments about why he doesn't do things like that) this question will absolutely not fit the SE format.  It is opinion based, and is not a good fit here.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast : The difference is, that for answering this question, the *exact* builds are not really needed. Two out of six are already solved.

Comment: Here is a link to [the 14th thread](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?485983-Class-and-Level-Geekery-XIV-We-are-the-Geek-Pantheon) Enjoy.  For a question here, pick one character, present your build (or what you think the build is) and then ask about optimization versus build presented.  That has a chance to be in scope.  As asked, this is both far too broad, not to mention opinion based.